# Connecting to Oracle Database ORA-01019 error message

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odbc

I am working on a VB.NET application which someone else made that has a form that connects to an Oracle 9.1 Database. Everytime the form opened I would get the following error message:

`"Oracle client and networking components were not found. These components are supplied by Oracle corporation and are part of the Oracle version 7.3.3"`

Since I couldn't find the 9.1 Client Install I installed the [Oracle Database 11g Release 2 Client (11.2.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (32-bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html).

So now I get the following error message:

`"Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019"`

Comment: You haven't installed Oracle correctly. Deinstall it and re-install the client, but this time do a full administrator install. Also, make sure that you are installing a 32-bit client on a 32-bit machine. Obvious I know, but you never know.

Comment: I uninstalled it via [these instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-1968077.html) and went ahead and installed [Oracle Database 12c Release 1 Client (12.1.0.1.0) for Microsoft Windows (64bit)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/database12c-win64-download-1968077.html). Still get the ORA-01019 error message.

Comment: Did you install it whilst logged on as an Administrator?

Comment: Yes. I make it a habbit.